# Automation layer above a site

Tags: ruby, automation, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm looking into creating a website that sits on top of another site. I wish for this site to be a sort of driver/auto-mater of the original site. The original site is slow and you need to input the same data repetitively (and lots of it - which is infuriating)

What would be the best way of doing this.

I have started using `watir-webdriver` in `ruby`, and it seems to work well! Would I be able to host this? I know it launches an explorer (fire-fox in my case) and my worry is not being able to host the application?

I don't want to place all my eggs into this one basket and find out later there's a stumbling block to getting it done!

Comment: Hey. I think you need to be more specific: are you thinking of creating an HTML test harness that interacts with your web application? If so, why not use that effort rewriting the site to perform better?

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer**

I think there are better tools for web scraping than web testing tools (watir and others), and your end result might require a lot more work than you imagine.

**The long answer**

This sounds like a case of the [façade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) in which your application would act as the new frontend and the old/existing site as the backend for the improved experience of the service.

Some things to think about before jumping into programming:

1. If the old site requires users to register, would your users be willing to re-register to your site so that you could log them in into the old site programmatically?
2. How frequently is the same data required to be inputted and how would you prevent it?
3. The existing site may have expectations on the request headers which might cause you extra headache and require quite some work to circumvent.
4. Are you allowed to use the existing site's user interface material or do you need to start from scratch?
5. How often is the existing site changed and how would it affect your application?

In summary, there are lots of factors and issues to take into account depending on how the existing site is implemented and who are your visioned users. Suggesting a best way to do it would require a lot more knowledge of both the existing site and how you'd want to improve it.

I haven't used `watir-webdriver` myself but if it is like Selenium and starts a new browser instance any time you run it, then hosting it would most likely not work as you'd expect. There are better tools for what you are thinking of doing, i.e. web scraping, and you may want to take a look at the following, for example:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Web_Content_Scrapers
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients

Comment: Thanks! I will start looking into those. The main application of the tool i am looking into developing is internal, so the internal team would not have to complete repetitive tasks, making them more efficient in the long run! We would not need to worry about other re-registering. But the launching of a new browser was an issue I was concerned about

Comment: Yes, you can cut many corners and do things differently when implementing something like that only for internal use. If you think my answer helped you, please mark it as the accepted answer.